# how to show number of decimal places based on its input?

Tags: php

I have used number_format() function for thousand separate, but this function get specific decimal places number. 
but I need the number of decimal place should be the number, that is passed to function

should be like this.

number           output

1234                 1,234

1234.9             1,234.9

1234.94            1,234.94

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  but in this function the decimal places is specific. I don't want decimal places to be zero for the integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use number_format() first and then trim, when needed, like so:

```
function formatter($input, $maxDecimals)
{
    $number = number_format($input, $maxDecimals);
    if ($maxDecimals > 0) {
        list($whole, $fraction) = explode(".", $number);
        $number =  $whole . rtrim("." . $fraction, ".0");
    }
    return $number;
}

echo formatter(0.0, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(100.0, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(100.01, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1200.9, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1200, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1200.9, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1234, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1234.9, 6).'<br>';
echo formatter(1234.94, 6).'<br>';
```

The trim will remove any zero's and dot at the end. The above code will return:

> 0
>   100
>   100.01
>   1,200.9
>   1,200
>   1,200.9
>   1,234
>   1,234.9
>   1,234.94

Comment: @Andreas Ah, good point. I'll rethink this a bit... hold on. :-)

Comment: @jumahMohammadi no it doesn't, look at the link above

Comment: @Andreas It should work now, but I hope that jumahMohammadi got the message. SO drives you to answer questions quickly, but sometimes accurary suffers because of that.

Comment: @Andreas I used only the rtrim()  function. and it solved my problem, but anyway i will use the changed codes

Comment: @jumahMohammadi Andreas has a good point. When a number ends in zeros like `100` it would have trimmed the zeros there as well and return `1`. _Not good!_

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oh yes. do you have any other idea for it.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your good point. I did not check it with numbers that end in zero.  do you have any idea for it?

Comment: @jumahMohammadi I have since updated my answer and the problem doesn't exist anymore. But you have to use the updated answer. It will only happen when you set the `$maxDecimals` value to zero.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i used the updated answer, but it also not show the zero

Comment: @jumahMohammadi I'll have a look. One moment.

Comment: @jumahMohammadi OK, this clearly is more finicky than I though. I think I got it right now. Hopefully. I updated the answer again.